# Classical MVC in Cocoa

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller

I'm trying to structure some view-code out of the controller (obviously without using a nib). Therefore, I tried a simple example, but for some reason, I can't add the target to the button in the controller, rest is fine. Here's what I'm trying:

Controller.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "IndexView.h"

@interface IndexController : UIViewController
{

}

@property (nonatomic) IndexView *contentView;

@end
```

Controller.m

```
#import "IndexController.h"
#import "IndexView.h"

@interface IndexController ()

@end

@implementation IndexController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        self.contentView = [[IndexView alloc]init];
        [self.view addSubview:self.contentView];

        [self connectUIElements];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) connectUIElements
{
    [self.contentView.testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(testButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

#pragma mark --
#pragma mark UIHandler
- (void) testButtonClicked
{
    NSLog(@"testbutton clicked");
}

@end
```

View.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface IndexView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *testButton;

@end
```

View.m

```
#import "IndexView.h"

@implementation IndexView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        [self setUpView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        [self setUpView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) setUpView
{
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    self.testButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 100, 50)];
    self.testButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.testButton setTitle:@"hello, world" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self addSubview:self.testButton];
}

@end
```

I'm just exploring possibilities to get closer to a classical MVC pattern and a little farther away from Apples mediator-interpretation. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried making your `IndexView` outlet `strong`?

Comment: isn't strong default? should affect only the retaincycle anyway, afaik

Comment: You init the view with `[[IndexView alloc]init]`, so I wonder if `initWithFrame` and `setUpView` of `IndexView` is called at all ...

Comment: added a plain init, the button still shows up, but doesn't get connected

Comment: What happens if you call `initWithFrame` in your view controller instead?

Comment: uh, that does it! don'T understand why, though! make it an answer, so I can accept it 8)

Comment: @MarcusToepper: I have added an answer, I'm glad that it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create your view using `initWithFrame:`, which is the default initializer for `UIView`. (The reason that is does not work with a simple `init` - but I am guessing here! - might be that the views size is zero and therefore the touch events do not work.)

Comment: just another thing: replacing the controller's own view with your custom view doesn't work either, you have to add it as subview.